# Web scraping in R with rvest: problem finding tags

Tags: css, r

I'm triying to use rvest library in order to annotate some data of an url.
This process had worked well with previous urls and data, but this time I'm experiencing difficulties in finding the associated CSS 'tag' for the data I want to extract.

The url is:
https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/variant/8-52733231-G-A?dataset=gnomad_r2_1
I am particularly interested in the value of European Allele frecuency (see image):

[image]

I have tried to find the associated CSS tag for this number by searching in the source code. I have also tried some chrome extensions to reveal the tags (SelectorGadget)... but all my attempts were in vane. The result is always the same: {xml_nodeset (0)}

My code is:

```
url <-'https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/variant/8-52733231-G-A?dataset=gnomad_r2_1'
webpage <- read_html(url)
europ.freq<- html_nodes(webpage,'CSS_tag')
europ.freq
```

Can anyone help me with this??

Thanks a lot in advanced!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

WOW Kikoralston!

Thank you very much for your detailed answer and kindness. I really apreciate it!!!!!
:D   :D  :D   :D
After some problems defining the binary path of firefox, that I finally solved with:

```
rs <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", 
               extraCapabilities = list(`mox:firefoxOptions` = list(binary = "C://Program Files (x86)//Mozilla Firefox//firefox.exe")))
```

It worked perfect!!!! :D

Thanks Thanks Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help! Like I said, I struggled with this issue too. If you think my answer solved your problem (although you had to tweak it a bit), please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers and also helps other people with a questions similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a long answer. But when I started scraping these websites, I struggled with it. So I just want to give you a context of what is going on.

### Why is this happening?

The reason you are getting an empty list in your results is simple: it's because the nodes are not there!

You can check out by yourself by printing the raw html source code that `read_html(url)` function returns in this case

```
> webpage %>% as.character()
[1] "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<title>gnomAD</title>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<meta name=\"description\" content=\"The Genome Aggregation Database (gnomAD) is a resource developed by an international coalition of investigators, with the goal of aggregating and harmonizing both exome and genome sequencing data from a wide variety of large-scale sequencing projects, and making summary data available for the wider scientific community.\">\n<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\">\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css\">\n<link rel=\"search\" href=\"/opensearch.xml\" type=\"application/opensearchdescription+xml\" title=\"gnomAD\">\n<style>body,html{height:100%;width:100%;background-color:#fafafa;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,\"Segoe UI\",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,\"Helvetica Neue\",sans-serif;font-size:14px}@media print{body,html{background:0 0}}</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<div id=\"root\"></div>\n<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-85987017-1\"></script><script>function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)}window.gaTrackingId=\"UA-85987017-1\",window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[],gtag(\"js\",new Date),gtag(\"config\",\"UA-85987017-1\",{send_page_view:!1}),window.gtag=gtag</script><script src=\"/js/bundle-8c98b722b9c7c14b5bbc.js\"></script>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

As you can see the html code is pretty small. Not much there. This is because this request you make to the url in R returns just an empty template for the webpage. In your web browser, this webpage is built dynamically. Your first request starts a chain of subsequent requests that executes JS scripts, downloads images, downloads data, ... And all these subsequent requests update the content of your webpage so you get the end result you see in your browser.

If you look in chrome's developer tools (image below), you can see all this chain of requests

[image]

The request on the top is the one you made with `read_html`. Then the webpage it returned gets updated by all these subsequent requests.

Usually, these types of dashboard applications have one specific request made in the middle that returns a json string with all the data to populate the website. In chrome you can filter the json responses by clicking the "XHR" button in the top of the screen. In this specific case, it is that request I marked with a red arrow.

So one solution is to go through the json responses and find the one that has the data you want. Then repeat this request in R (in this case it is a `POST` request) and parse the response using json parsing functions (like `jsonlite::fromJSON()`).

But my experience with this is that sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. I am not always sure how to make that specific request to the server. Sometimes there are formatting issues. Sometimes there are state variables that your browser sets and you have to figure out how to do it...

A probably better solution is to use `RSelenium` (which I just recently started trying to use)

### Solution with RSelenium

A couple of nice tutorials on `RSelenium`:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html
http://joshuamccrain.com/tutorials/web_scraping_R_selenium.html

With `RSelenium` you are actually running your web browser. So all those subsequent calls are also happening. The webpage gets built dynamically and you have the nodes (and the data) you are looking for.

I am running a Mac and I could not make RSelenium work with Google Chrome. With firefox it worked perfectly. Maybe it will work for you. I am still learning the details of RSelenium. So maybe you could change some of these parameters in `rsDriver`.

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"), port = 4568L,
               chromever = NULL,
               iedrver = NULL, 
               phantomver = NULL,
               version="3.141.59")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate('https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/variant/8-52733231-G-A?dataset=gnomad_r2_1')

# remDr$getPageSource() returns a list with the html code as string
# use read_html to convert it into something that rvest can parse
webpage <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html()

# html_table() returns all tables in the webpage as data frames
# the one you want is the second one
df.table <- webpage %>% html_table() %>% .[[2]]

# close browser and stop server
rD$client$close()
rD$server$stop()

print(df.table)
```

(note that I did not search by css tag because in your example it was easier to just get the whole table. But you could also get an specific node by css tag if you wanted to)

And the results is:

```
                 Population               Population Allele Count Allele Number Number of Homozygotes Allele Frequency
1    European (non-Finnish)   European (non-Finnish)        13779         65426                     0           0.2106
2  African/African-American African/African-American         2264         14050                     0           0.1611
3               South Asian              South Asian         2193         13982                     0           0.1568
4   Latino/Admixed American  Latino/Admixed American         2792         18084                     0           0.1544
5                East Asian               East Asian         1869         12272                     0           0.1523
6        European (Finnish)       European (Finnish)         1665         12042                     0           0.1383
7          Ashkenazi Jewish         Ashkenazi Jewish          592          4344                     0           0.1363
8                     Other                    Other          509          3888                     0           0.1309
9                    Female                   Female        11460         66844                     0           0.1714
10                     Male                     Male        14203         77244                     0           0.1839
11                    Total                    Total        25663        144088                     0           0.1781
```

The data value you want is in `` df.table$`Allele Frequency`[1] ``.

There are more things you can do, like clicking in the webpage or submitting forms to update the data in the page. I suggest having a look at those two links I listed above. I am still learning about it too.